# Reciprocal of a quaternion in matrix form

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am given the definition that

$$ q\longleftrightarrow \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      z&w\\
      -\overline{w}&\overline{z}
    \end{array}
\right], q = z + j \overline{w}, z = x_0 + i x_1, w = x_2+ix_3 $$

If I want to find the reciprocal of $q$, I know it is $\overline{q} = \overline{z + j \overline{w} } = \overline{z} - j w $. What would be the matrix representation of $\overline{q}$ ?

Comment: Applying that same definition, the matrix of $\bar q$ would be $$\pmatrix{\bar z & -\bar w\\ w& z}$$

Comment: Note that $\bar q$ is the *conjugate* of $q$, not the reciprocal.

Comment: To further clarify: the conjugate of a quaternion is equal to its reciprocal if and only if $q$ has unit norm, i.e. when $|z|^2+|w|^2=1$.